# reading boolean condition from config file?

Tags: python, json, parsing, configuration, config

What's the best way to read a condition from a config file in Python using `ConfigParser` and `json`? I want to read something like:

```
[mysettings]
x >= 10
y < 5
```

and then apply it to code where `x` and `y` are defined variables, and the condition will be applied as to the values of `x, y` in the code.  Something like:

```
l = get_lambda(settings["mysettings"][0])
if l(x):
  # do something
  pass
l2 = get_lambda(settings["mysettings"][1])
if l2(y):
  # do something
  pass
```

ideally I'd like to specify conditions like `x + y >= 6` too.

there must be a better way, but the idea is to constrain the values of variables using simple boolean expressions from the config file.

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON?

Comment: json can be used to parse Python eval'able structures

Comment: Yes, but the config format you are showing is not JSON.

Comment: Is the config file considered *trusted* input? If so, why not define it in Python and `import` it?

Comment: Do you have a list of practical options - or is someone to expected to be able to use `(x + y / 2) + y * 2.1 + z >= otherval / anotherval` ?

Comment: *"json can be used to parse Python eval'able structures"* - exactly. Data structures, but not expressions. Conditions are [expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you want—or need—to use both `configparser` *and* `json`, as both are sufficient by itself. Here's how to do it with each one:

Say you had a config file from a *trusted* source that contained something like this:

**`myconfig.ini`**

```
[mysettings]
other=stuff
conds=
    x >= 10
    y < 5
    x + y >= 6
```

It could parsed and used like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
try:
    import configparser
except ImportError:  # Python 2
    import ConfigParser as configparser

get_lambda = lambda expr: lambda **kwargs: bool(eval(expr, kwargs))

cp = configparser.ConfigParser()
cp.read('myconfig.ini')

exprs = cp.get('mysettings', 'conds').strip()
conds = [expr for expr in exprs.split('\n')]

l = get_lambda(conds[0])
l2 = get_lambda(conds[1])
l3 = get_lambda(conds[2])

def formatted(l, c, **d):
    return '{:^14} : {:>10} -> {}'.format(
        ', '.join('{} = {}'.format(var, val) for var, val in sorted(d.items())), c, l(**d))

l = get_lambda(conds[0])
print('l(x=42): {}'.format(l(x=42)))
print()
print(formatted(l, conds[0], x=42))
print(formatted(l2, conds[1], y=6))
print(formatted(l3, conds[2], x=3, y=4))
```

Which would result in the following output:

```
l(x=42): True

    x = 42     :    x >= 10 -> True
    y = 6      :      y < 5 -> False
 x = 3, y = 4  : x + y >= 6 -> True
```

If the information the was instead kept in a JSON-format file similar to this:

**`myconfig.json`**

```
{
    "mysettings": {
        "other": "stuff",
        "conds": [
          "x >= 10",
          "y < 5",
          "x + y >= 6"
        ]
    }
}
```

It could be easily parsed with the `json` module and used in a similar fashion:

```
import json

with open('myconfig.json') as file:
    settings = json.loads(file.read())

conds = settings['mysettings']['conds']
```

...the remainder would be the identical and produce the same results. i.e.:

```
l = get_lambda(conds[0])
print('l(x=42): {}'.format(l(x=42)))
print()
print(formatted(l, conds[0], x=42))
print(formatted(l2, conds[1], y=6))
print(formatted(l3, conds[2], x=3, y=4))
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an example using Python itself as the language for describing the config file:

**config.py**

```
mysettings = [
    lambda x: x >= 10,
    lambda y: y < 5,
]
```

**main.py**

```
from config import mysettings

a = 42
b = 300

for i, condition in enumerate(mysettings):
    for value in (a, b):
        result = condition(value)
        print "condition %s for value %s is: %s" % (i, value, result)
```

**Output:**

```
condition 0 for value 42 is: True
condition 0 for value 300 is: True
condition 1 for value 42 is: False
condition 1 for value 300 is: False
```

This of course assumes that the config file is considered **trusted** input, because by doing `condition(value)` you'll execute whatever function is defined in the config file.

But I don't see any way around that, regardless of what language you're using: conditions are [expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html) and therefore *executable code*. If you want to end up with a Python expression that you can just use in your code, you'll have to evaluate that expression sooner or later.

**Edit:**

If for some reason you really can't use Python, this is how you could do it with a config file in JSON:

**config.json**

```
{
  "mysettings": {
    "color": "Blue",
    "expressions": [
      "x >= 10",
      "y < 5"
    ]
  },
  "other_settings": {
    "color": "red"
  }
}
```

**main.py**

```
import json

x = 42
y = 300


def eval_expr(expr, values):
    result = eval(expr, values.copy())
    print "The expression '%s' evaluates to '%s' for the values %r" % (
                                                    expr, result, values)
    return result


f = open('config.json')
data = json.loads(f.read())
settings = data["mysettings"]

for expr in settings['expressions']:
    values = dict(x=x, y=y)
    eval_expr(expr, values)
```

Result:

```
The expression 'x >= 10' evaluates to 'True' for the values {'y': 300, 'x': 42}
The expression 'y < 5' evaluates to 'False' for the values {'y': 300, 'x': 42}
```

Or, closer to your example:

```
x = 1
y = 2
values = dict(x=x, y=y)

e1 = settings['expressions'][0]
if eval_expr(e1, values):
    # do something
    pass

e2 = settings['expressions'][1]
if eval_expr(e2, values):
    # do something else
    pass
```

Result:

```
The expression 'x >= 10' evaluates to 'False' for the values {'y': 2, 'x': 1}
The expression 'y < 5' evaluates to 'True' for the values {'y': 2, 'x': 1}
```

Comment: I want to read the expression from a text file though, which contains other settings, not from a `.py` file. Can it be adapted to that?

Comment: @user248237 Well, why not store those other settings in `config.py` as well? Sure, you could do the whole `read()` -> `eval()` dance, but why bother if you don't have to? If you do in fact have an existing config file (format) that you can't change, you'd have to store literal Python expressions in it, and eventually `eval()` them.

Comment: @user248237 So can the config file be considered trusted input or not?

Comment: @user248237 Updated my answer with an example in JSON